# Single legend for plots in primary and secondary axes

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I created a plot with two data sets, in a primary and secondary Y axes, respectively, using

```
[ ha, hl1, hl2 ] = plotyy( xr, yr, xq, yq );
```

Then I formatted the lines with

```
set( hl1, 'Linestyle', '-' );  set( hl1, 'Color', 'b' );   % solid, blue
set( hl2, 'Linestyle', '--' );  set( hl2, 'Color', 'r' );  % dash, red
```

and I finally created a common legend for both with

```
hl = legend( [ hl1, hl2 ], 'r', '\theta/\pi' );
```

I guess it is not important the contents of `( xr, yr, xq, yq )`. The two lines are correctly plotted, and each one on the correct axis.

The first line in the legend should have a (solid, blue) line, and
the second line should have a (dash, red) line.
The result is the opposite (see figure).

[image: legend]

This is the same if I use

```
hl = legend( [ hl2, hl1 ], 'r', '\theta/\pi' );
```

and if I change the comma by a semicolon `[ hl2; hl1 ]`.
What is the right way of doing it?

Comment: I would set the `DisplayName` of your plots. `set(hl1, 'DisplayName', 'r')`. Although, I agree that is unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Suever - I just did that, and I created the legend with the same command as before. It doesn't work.

Comment: If you do that, then *do not* specify the second input to `legend`

Comment: @Suever - So what should the command be?

Comment: `legend([hl1, hl2])`

Comment: @Suever - Now I see no legend. And no errors. I tried using `set( hl, 'Visible', 'on');`. No luck.

Comment: Hmmm I'd have to see your code using `DisplayName` to see what's happening

Comment: @Suever - I cleaned up everyithing, and left code like ederag's as a starting point for debugging. It turns out that a later line `set( hl, 'fontsize', 20 )` was causing the inversion. To confirm this, I added such line after ederag's code, and it inverts the lines in the legend. It is quite strange to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using code like ederag's

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 101);
[ha, hl1, hl2] = plotyy(x, sin(x), x, -sin(x));
set( hl1, 'Linestyle', '-' );  set( hl1, 'Color', 'b' );   % solid, blue
set( hl2, 'Linestyle', '--' );  set( hl2, 'Color', 'r' );  % dash, red
hl = legend( [ hl1, hl2 ], 'r', '\theta/\pi' );
```

I found out that adding the line

```
set( hl, 'fontsize', 20 );
```

after it inverts the lines in the legend. As far as I understand, this is unexpecetd (possibly a bug?).

Answer (score 1):

with octave-4.0.1-rc4, default graphics_toolkit ("qt"), the result seems fine.

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 101);
[ha, hl1, hl2] = plotyy(x, sin(x), x, -sin(x));
set( hl1, 'Linestyle', '-' );  set( hl1, 'Color', 'b' );   % solid, blue
set( hl2, 'Linestyle', '--' );  set( hl2, 'Color', 'r' );  % dash, red
hl = legend( [ hl1, hl2 ], 'r', '\theta/\pi' );
```

[image]

Except the `\theta/\pi` is not correctly interpreted. 
No need to file a bug report, since it has been solved in the development version.
But with 4.0.1 and `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")` the plot is fine:

[image]

So it might be time to upgrade. Here are the [ftp site](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/) and [windows installers](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/).

Comment: I cleaned up everyithing, and left code like yours as a starting point for debugging. It turns out that a later line `set( hl, 'fontsize', 20 )` was causing the inversión.